# "Length of the data to decrypt is invalid" exception while converting to string

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using Windows Live Id service for logging and authentication for my application. I get a token in the response sent by the Windows Live Id Service after the user get authenticated. I wish to decode this token in order to obtain the Unique Identifier out of it.Here is the link which explains this better:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb676622.aspx

I see exceptions while debugging in visual studio when I try to create a CryptoStream Object although the code does not break.

But when I try to convert the stream to bytes it throws an error and the code breaks.

It says:

"Length of the data to decrypt is invalid"

Here is the code that I am using:

```
     string token="";                     //Token Sent by the service
     string SecretKey = "";              //SecretKey Obtained while registering my application
     byte[] cryptKey = derive(secretKey, "ENCRYPTION");  


    static byte[] derive(string secret, string prefix)
      {
         using(HashAlgorithm hashAlg = HashAlgorithm.Create("SHA256"))
         { 
          const int keyLength = 16;
          byte[] data = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(prefix+secret);
          byte[] hashOutput = hashAlg.ComputeHash(data);
          byte[] byteKey = new byte[keyLength];
          Array.Copy(hashOutput, byteKey, keyLength);
          return byteKey;
         }
      }

    const int ivLength = 16;
    token = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(token);
    byte[] ivAndEncryptedValue = Convert.FromBase64String(token);
    aesAlg = new RijndaelManaged();
    aesAlg.KeySize = 128;
    aesAlg.Key = cryptKey;
    aesAlg.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
    memStream = new MemoryStream(ivAndEncryptedValue);
    byte[] iv = new byte[ivLength];
    memStream.Read(iv, 0, ivLength);
    aesAlg.IV = iv; 
    cStream = new CryptoStream(memStream, aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read);
    sReader = new StreamReader(cStream, Encoding.ASCII);
```

The next line of code throws error: "Length of the data to decrypt is invalid"

```
    decodedValue = sReader.ReadToEnd();    //Throws error:"Length of the data to decrypt is invalid"
```

Does anyone have any idea as to what can be the reason behind this?

Any kind of help or guidance will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Regards,

Abhishek

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of something that I currently use when Decrypting a value 
I hope that this will help you in regards to seeing what you have done incorrectly in your existing code

```
static string Decrypt() 
    {            
      byte[] keyBytes = Convert.FromBase64String("U6XksFkhWV4.......eo3fRg=="");
      byte[] iv = Convert.FromBase64String("KLnP....wA=="");
      byte[] cipherTextBytes = Convert.FromBase64String("Put the EncryptedText here");

      var symmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged { Mode = CipherMode.CBC, IV = iv, KeySize = 128, Key = keyBytes, Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros};

      using (var decryptor = symmetricKey.CreateDecryptor())
      using (var ms = new MemoryStream(cipherTextBytes))
      using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read)) {
        var plainTextBytes = new byte[cipherTextBytes.Length];
        int decryptedByteCount = cs.Read(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length);
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plainTextBytes, 0, decryptedByteCount);
      }
    }
```

Comment: I appreciate your help. I did try a similar code from another post but it did not seem to be working. I am really finding it hard to figure what the actual problem is.Thanks once again.....